# how to solve that zsh terminal cannot find any command?

Tags: terminal, zsh

I guess I made some mistake when I set environment path setting in zsrhc file. After that I cannot use any command in terminal even basic command like ls, pwd, cal, man, git ...... only able to use cd, pwd I checked. Result of searching solutions about it and implemented, now it shows nothing when I  command echo $PATH. I think zshrc file is cleared, it also be problem if there's really nothing..

So Conclusionally the question I want to ask first that how to solve the problem cannot use any command in zsh?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can either

- use the full path of commands e.g. /usr/bin/man
- set the path on the command line temporarily e.g.

  ```
    export PATH=$PATH:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
  ```

Use one of those mechanisms to enable you to edit your .zsrhc file